# jQuery/JavaScript how to get value of button that click on it, each row of buttons can only active only one button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs

I have a list of buttons with numeric values or odds.
on click of button i want the actives button value display on right side but if the button deactivate the value is replaced with new value or empty ,in row there is only one value because there is only one active button in row.

[image]

```html
<div class="bet-grid__pseudo-row">
                <div class="bet-grid__cell bet-grid__cell--match-result">
                  <button value="3.88" class="bet-grid__bet-button" >
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">1</div>
                    <div  class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="4.83" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">X</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">4.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="5.53" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">2</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">1.83</div>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="bet-grid__cell bet-grid__cell--double-chance">
                  <button value="2.63" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">1X</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="1.13" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">12</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="2.02" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">X2</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="bet-grid__cell bet-grid__cell--gg">
                  <button value="1.03" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">Yes</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">2.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="5.33" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">No</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: can you share your javascript logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say your active button class is just "active". So the active buttons have the classes "bet-grid__bet-button active". And your your trigger button has a class named "place-bet-btn" the following code with jquery would be your choice

```js
$(document).on('click', '.place-bet-btn', function (){
  let values = [];
  $('.bet-grid__bet-button.active').each(function(){
      values.push($(this).val()); 
  });
  console.log(values);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bet-grid__pseudo-row">
                <div class="bet-grid__cell bet-grid__cell--match-result">
                  <button value="3.88" class="bet-grid__bet-button active" >
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">1</div>
                    <div  class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="4.83" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">X</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">4.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="5.53" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">2</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">1.83</div>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="bet-grid__cell bet-grid__cell--double-chance">
                  <button value="2.63" class="bet-grid__bet-button active">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">1X</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="1.13" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">12</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="2.02" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">X2</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="bet-grid__cell bet-grid__cell--gg">
                  <button value="1.03" class="bet-grid__bet-button active">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">Yes</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">2.83</div>
                  </button>
                  <button value="5.33" class="bet-grid__bet-button">
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-left">No</div>
                    <div class="bet-grid__bet-button-right">3.83</div>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button class="place-bet-btn">Place Bet</button>
```